# XAML Parse Exception when attempting to read from database using System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Schema for tables:

```
CREATE TABLE songOrder(songid int, pos int, stanza int, foreign key(songid) 
references songs(id));

CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE stanzas using fts3(pos int, lyrics text, songid int);

CREATE TABLE songs(id integer primary key, name text);
```

Code that is causing the crash:

```
        InitilizeComponent();
        using (SQLiteConnection db = new 
        SQLiteConnection("DataSource=test.db;Version=3"))
        {
            db.Open();

            String sql = "select name from songs";
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, db))
            using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    //This is the line causing the crash
                    //Program runs just fine when this line does not execute
                    Debug.WriteLine(reader["id"]);
                    songs.Add(new song() {Name = (string)reader["name"]});
                }   
            }
            db.Close();
        }
        lbSongs.ItemsSource = songs;
```

Exception that is shown to me in Visual Studio:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' 
occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type
's3IO_Test.MainWindow'
that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.'
Line number '3' line position '9'.
```

If I look at the output I see this:
     A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in
     System.Data.SQLite.dll

The rest of the code works if I start with an empty database (meaning that while loop would not execute in the first place), so I don't know why trying to read the primary key causes an xmlparseexception, the two seem very unrelated to me.

I was writing to the Debug because I had thought that adding an "int id" variable to the song class was somehow causing the crash.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement

```
String sql = "select name from songs";
```

is only ever returning the column `name` from the `songs` table.

If you change to this:

```
String sql = "select id, name from songs";
```

the line `Debug.WriteLine(reader["id"]);`  should function properly.

The error is due to attempting to access a column that does not exist in the `SQLiteDataReader` using the given column name.

There are improvements that you can make to the code in terms of @HighCore's comment but they are outside the scope of this question.